# Serialize a .NET object

Tags: c#, serialization

To save all settings of my app, I use Serialization in a file, as described in this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C

So I created a class called Keyboard

```
[Serializable()]
class Keyboard : ISerializable
{
    private DeviceInf _infoKbd;
    private Screen _displayAttached;
}
```

When I start my program, the app crash during serialization, saying that Screen isn't serializable. So my question is: how to serialize a .NET that isn't serializable at the begin?

Comment: Are Screen and DeviceInf also marked as [Serializable()] ?

Comment: Inherit from the Screen class and make your inherited class `Serializable`? (If you're using the Windows.System.Forms Screen class, that is). If it's yours, just mark it as serializable.

Comment: To serialize Keyboard, all properties must be serializable. Your exception pointed that the Screen class is not serializable.

Comment: It is why I want to make the Screen object serializable!

Comment: You can't do that. Screen is not marked serializable and had no default ctor (used with XmlSerializer for example). So, I guess it would be difficult to write your own serialiser... (like in the link given by Beaner). You can't serialise the full object, but maybe use another one to store everything you want (and make it serializable).

Answer (score 1):

The **System.Windows.Forms.Screen** object is not marked as Searializable so .NET isn't going to do the heavy lifting for you. You can write you own serialiser though. An example of serializing a form can be found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86503/Saving-the-state-serializing-a-Windows-Form. If you don't want to do that maybe you can save your settings in and app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have to make DeviceInfo and Screen also serializable.